# TWIG: form_widget with type number

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I'm trying to change the "text" type of a input using Twig and Silex but looks that I'm doing something wrong.

This is the basic code I'm doing:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    {{ form_label("Id") }}
    {{ form_widget("id", { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
</div>
```

I want that this id field be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

in Symfony you need to change the type in your formtype:

```
->add('streetNo', NumberType::class, ['required' => true])
```

For older versions of Symfony it looks like this:

```
->add('streetNo','number', ['required' => true])
```

The twig "doesn't care" about the input type. I would think that it is the same for Silex as it is build on Symfony.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way. Thanks.